# Tabs and spaces in Angular 2 Component Decorator definition throw an unhandled exception

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I was refactoring my Angular 2 component code giving some tabulations and then the code stop working, when I removed the tabulation (spaces) it worked again.

```
@Component({
  templateUrl   : './app.component.html',
  styleUrls     : ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

The above code doesn't work. This works:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

It is a really weird behaviour.

[image: unhandled exception promise]

UPDATE: 
I'm using webpack with awesome-typescript-loader and angular2-template-loader, this is the code transpiled:

With tabs and spaces compile to this: 
[image: not working code transpiled]

But, without the tabs and spaces compile to this: 
[image: working code]

It seems like the webpack loaders are not recognizing the code with spaces between the ":" of the object decorator definition.

Comment: Are you using a linting which might cause the code to not compile? (in case you are using typescript or es2015)

Comment: seems lot like what I mentioned, something is preventing the file to be compiled, try to figure out what linting tool is used in the project

Comment: I just update with the transpiled codes, it looks like without the spaces in the decorator definition webpack replaces it so it can work with the webpack dev server,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it was the Angular2-template-loader. Updating to v0.6.0 fix the issue.